# How can I display map data (prefererably using OpenStreetMaps) in my java application?

Tags: java, swing, openstreetmap

I currently have an Android app that downloads map data from tile.openstreetmap.org. I then want it to be able to communicate with a server and have them share the same map markers. The solution I am using for Android does not really port over to standard Java and I was wondering:

**Is there a relatively easy way to display the same map data on my desktop using java?**

Currently the maps are in .mgm files using a 1-tile-per-file format. If there are any questions I can answer to make answering my question easier, please let me know. Thanks ahead of time.

EDIT:

My fault... I forgot to mention that I need to be able to have the map data downloaded in some way because I cannot guarantee a consistent internet connection to my desktop (yes, I realize how strange that sounds), however, I need to guarantee that map data can be provided.

Edit 2:

I think a lot of this is taken care of by updated and new APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been answered other places on Stack Overflow:

[OpenStreetMap - java library to handle offline map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403547/openstreetmap-java-library-to-handle-offline-map)

The basic premise is to setup a local tileserver with pre-rendered OSM tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with [JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)? It should work with OpenStreetMap data.

Comment: looks mostly promising... Still investigating... thanks though

Comment: +1 There's no support for using offline maps, thanks for trying though

Answer (score 2):

[`JMapViewer`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) was recently updated and works nicely.

> Last Changed Date: 2011-08-10 10:50:46 -0400 (Wed, 10 Aug 2011)

Comment: oh wait... did you use the source code snapshot or the last release?

Comment: +1 There's no support for using offline maps, thanks for trying though

Comment: Yes, I had just done `svn update`. Sorry this didn't help. Any way to set up your own `.mgm` server as a tile source?